# How to access an annotation inside a closure in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, closures

I have created a custom annotation from a class:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class annotationCustom: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

    var coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title : NSString!
    var subtitle : NSString!

    init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: NSString!, subtitle: NSString!){

        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
    }

}
```

I then fetch a set of coordinates using parses query: `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` which gathers the coordinates inside a closure. I then use them coordinates on a Map.

```
       var otherUsersLat = coord.latitude as Double
       var otherUsersLong = coord.longitude as Double

                    //Other Users coords.
           var location = CLLocation(latitude: otherUsersLat, longitude: otherUsersLong)
           let latitude:CLLocationDegrees = location.coordinate.latitude
           let longitude:CLLocationDegrees = location.coordinate.longitude
           let latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.003
           let lonDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.003
           let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)
           let finalLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
           let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(finalLocation, span)
                    self.myMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

I then set the annotation on the map.

```
for name in names {
                        if name == PFUser.currentUser().username {
                             var userAnnotation = annotationCustom(coordinate: finalLocation, title: "You are here", subtitle: "Hey")
                            self.myMap.addAnnotation(userAnnotation)
                        } else {
                            var otherAnnotation = annotationCustom(coordinate: finalLocation, title: name, subtitle: "Hey")
                            self.myMap.addAnnotation(otherAnnotation)
                        }
```

I have created two annotations, one for the current user and one for other users. I am trying to change the properties of just the `userAnnotation`.

I have tried using the method:

```
 func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

        var view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: userAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")
        view.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColor.Green

        return view
    }
```

Which cannot access the userAnnotation as it is inside the closure? Does anyone have any ideas. I'm still kinda of new to Swift and closures etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem doesn't really have anything to do with closures specifically.

It has more to do with variable scope and how external data should be processed in delegate methods.

The `userAnnotation` variable is declared locally in an `if` block inside a `for` loop which all just happens to be inside a closure.  The `userAnnotation` variable is actually only accessible using that name only in the `if` block.  That's its scope.

You *could* move the declaration of `userAnnotation` to a higher level (like at the view controller's class level) so that it's visible in the `if` block inside the closure and the delegate method.

That may compile and may even seem to "work" but it's not reliable and not recommended here.

The `viewForAnnotation` delegate method is not guaranteed to be called immediately after `addAnnotation` nor is it guaranteed to be called only once for each annotation.  It would be very difficult or impossible to make sure your external variable's value is in sync with what annotation the delegate method is being called for.

---

The `viewForAnnotation` delegate method already provides a reference to the annotation it is being called for through the `annotation` argument.

The code in `viewForAnnotation` should only use the properties of the `annotation` argument passed to the method to determine the view characteristics.

Since the delegate method will be called for all annotations, you just need to have a way to tell annotations apart.

You *could* use the `title` and check if it's equal to "You are here" but that's not very flexible.  A better way is to add another property to the custom annotation class that specifically helps you identify whether the annotation is the "user" annotation.

A simple way to do that is just add a boolean property like `isUserAnnotation`.  Set it to `true` only for the `userAnnotation` and in `viewForAnnotation`, set the `pinColor` based on the value of `isUserAnnotation`.

For example:

1. Add the property to the annotation class:

   ```
   var subtitle : NSString!
   var isUserAnnotation : Bool  // <-- new property
   ```
2. Default the property to `false` in the `init` method:

   ```
   self.subtitle = subtitle
   self.isUserAnnotation = false
   ```
3. When creating `userAnnotation`, set the new property to `true`:

   ```
   var userAnnotation = annotationCustom(coordinate: finalLocation, title: "You are here", subtitle: "Hey")
   userAnnotation.isUserAnnotation = true
   self.myMap.addAnnotation(userAnnotation)

   //For OtherAnnotation, you could set the property to false
   //or do nothing since it's defaulted to false in the init method.
   ```
4. In `viewForAnnotation`, set the `pinColor` based on the value of `isUserAnnotation` obtained from the `annotation` object passed into the method:

   ```
   var view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")

   if let ac = annotation as? annotationCustom {
       if ac.isUserAnnotation {
           view.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColor.Green
       }
       else {
           view.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColor.Red
       }
   }

   return view
   ```

Comment: Thank you, this is a brilliant answer. I am obviously still new to everything so going through a huge learning curve. Thanks for breaking things down so well.